# How would you show that $AB$=$0$ $\iff$ col $B \subseteq$ null $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Assuming $A$ is $m\times n$ and $B$ is $n\times m$, and to show that $AB$=$0$ $\iff$ col $B \subseteq$ null $A$,  I set biconditional statement:

1. if $AB=0$, then $R_a\cdot C_b =0$ for all A rows and B columns and then I failed to continue.
2. if  col $B \subseteq$ null $A$, col $B$ is linear combination of null$A$ vectors......

I don't know how to start this type of question, so could anyone help? Thanks

Comment: Have you considered what it means to be an element of the null space of $A$?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the definition of multiplication of a vector on the left by a matrix, you'll see that the result always lies in the column space of the matrix. Let $C_i$ be the columns of $B$ and let $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ be the components of a vector $v$ in the relevant basis. Then
$$Bv=\sum_i{v_iC_i}$$
If we apply $A$ to this we get
$$ABv=\sum_i{v_iA(C_i)}$$
This is always $0$ for all choices of $v$ if and only if $A(C_i)=0$ for all $i$, which is exactly the same as saying $\mathrm{col}\ B\subseteq\mathrm{null}\ A$.

Answer (score 0):

Just notice that if $B = \begin{pmatrix}
\vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots \\
B_1 & B_2 & \cdots & B_m \\
\vdots & \vdots & & \vdots
\end{pmatrix}$, then $AB = \begin{pmatrix}
\vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots \\
A B_1 & A B_2 & \cdots & AB_m \\
\vdots & \vdots & & \vdots
\end{pmatrix}$.

You can now easily see that $A B = 0 \Leftrightarrow (\forall 1 \leq k \leq m, A B_k = 0)$.

This should be easy to finish, now.

Comment: Um I understand AB=0 $\Rightarrow$ col B⊆null A, but how does the reverse work?

Comment: @1412 Use the fact that each $B_k \in \text{col}(B)$.